# Is there a single legitimate use case for DefVar?

Tags: vba, vb6

`Def[Type]` statements <s>spawned from Hell</s> are supported in VBA, seemingly to enforce some kind of [*Systems Hungarian*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) notation.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
DefBool B
DefLng I, L
```

These statements have the following side-effects:

```
Dim bSomething ' <~ that's a compile-time Boolean
Dim iGiveUp    ' <~ that's a compile-time Long
Dim lNooooo    ' <~ that's a compile-time Long also
```

And:

```
Public Function IsUseful()
' function returns a compile-time Long
End Function
```

Let's not forget:

```
Public Property Get BasicStuff()
' yep, that's a compile-time Boolean
End Property
```

You get the idea. `Def[Type]` statements are bloody evil and willingly using them in modern code should earn you 10K volts through the keyboard*.

But let's open up our minds, and pretend they're awesome for a minute.

There's a number of such statements:

- `DefBool` for implicitly-typed `Boolean`
- `DefCur` for implicitly-typed `Currency`
- `DefDbl` for implicitly-typed `Double`
- `DefInt` for implicitly-typed `Integer`
- `DefLng` for implicitly-typed `Long`
- `DefSng` for implicitly-typed `Single`

And then there's this one:

- `DefVar` for implicitly-typed `Variant`

Now, if you didn't know, this is also an implicitly-typed Variant:

```
Dim anything ' no "As [Type]" clause
```

So given implicit typing `Def[Type]` keywords are there to, well, *specify an implicit compile-time type* given a range of applicable first-letter prefixes...

```
DefVar V
Dim vSomeVariant   ' compile-time Variant (DefVar)
Dim foo            ' also a compile-time Variant (implicit)
Dim bar As Variant ' also a compile-time Variant (explicit)
Dim vRedundant As Long ' compile-time Long ("As [type]" clause overrides DefVar)
```

Even with an open-minded, Systems-Hungarian-Friendly approach, I cannot fathom a single legitimate use-case for `DefVar`. Is there one?

---

<sub>*Your mileage may vary.</sub>

Comment: It really seems like an unfinished thought or approach. It appears everyone agrees it should be avoided.  Perhaps at some point in time someone on a development team wanted to force typing on passed parameters with less typing?  Only way I see that it could speed things up a little or be even remotely useful in VBA, module scope force typing during parameter passing? . . . . . .

Comment: I was grasping at straws and here is another straw: apparently BASIC implemented in the 60's has a DEF keyword for functions, perhaps someone manipulated the keyword and carried it forward as VisualBasic came about around 1991.  Someone knows why but the answer could be 30 to 70 years old?

Comment: I vote for RubberDuck to enable the 10k voltage through the keyboard if `DefVar` is detected. Or at the very least throwing up a "cut that crap out!" dialog and forcing the user to change it.

Comment: Someone (or a group) didn't like to declare variables and just typed them on the fly with a preceding letter? From Wiki the default for undeclared is Variant but it can be over ridden assuming Option Explicit is not used: The default type may be overridden for a specific declaration by using a special suffix character on the variable name (# for Double, ! for Single, & for Long, % for Integer, $ for String, and @ for Currency) or using the key phrase As (type)

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code That's exactly the question - if it's implicitly `Variant`, why even have `DefVar` at all? Under what circumstances where would one actually need a `DefVar`? One would think to provide an override to some already specified `Def[Type]` but intersecting range causes a compile-time error about duplicate `DefType` statement so it can't be it. BTW, `Option Explicit` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code yeah, type hints predate the V of VB - I remember using them to declare/assign variables in BASIC 2.0 on Commodore-64.. AFAICT type hints were largely deprecated with the advent of the `As` keyword... There's gotta be a historical reason for `DefVar`, I just can't put the finger on it.

Comment: FWIW - in those older dialects, the default for untyped variables used to be `Single` -- those had no notions of `Variant`s at all.

Comment: I'm using `DefObj A-Z` on all my VB6 modules to safe-guard against untyped variables/params/functions (so these don't become `Variant`s). This way any kind of usage mostly bombs during compile-time. There is a bug in the compiler with public classes where some `DefType` is on: methods w/ no explicitly typed retvals are still (wrongly) recognized as returning `Variant`s and offer to break compatibility on each recompilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Def*type* statements come from much older versions of BASIC. I remember in QBasic at least, variables were floating-point by default, and one would use a suffix if one wanted a different variable. (So, X by itself would be a number, and you would use X$ instead for a String.) If one was doing math with integers (as one often did), one could use `DefInt A-Z` to declare that the "default" type would be Integer rather than floating-point, so that you didn't need to suffix all your variables with the `%` to indicate integer. Or maybe you would designate one section of starting letters for integers, and the rest for floating point, which might be useful particularly if you were porting code from FORTRAN or other older languages which used such conventions of different starting letters having different types.

A lot of Visual Basic was designed having in mind the use case of being able to directly use pieces of code from prior versions of BASIC with minimal changes, such as having line numbers or using "Let" to assign a variable. I'm not really a historian, but I think the "systems Hungarian" came later, particularly once people were in the habit of using more than a letter or two for their variable names as computers got powerful enough to handle such things. So I'm disagreeing a bit with your premise, as I think that Def*type* is just in BASIC because prior versions had it, not because it was designed to help enforce a particular coding style.

And I'm guessing that DefVar in particular was added just because they added Variant as a type and it seemed like Variant ought to be handled like the other types they had, though it amuses me to think that perhaps the programmer implementing it in the language thought it was just as useless as you do now.

Obviously there's not a lot of need for any Def*type*, or particularly DefVar, in anything that was created at a time where VB6 was "new", and certainly not for anything new now.

To answer your actual question, the only thing I can really think of is that it would help make explicit that you were intentionally using the default of unsuffixed and non-explicitly-typed variables should be treated as Variants. Perhaps in some modules in your application you used `DefInt A-Z`, and in other modules you used `DefVar A-Z`, just as a coding standard to ensure that any defaults were make explicit and could be easily understood. It's a bit of a stretch, but I've certainly heard of weirder coding standards.

And if nothing else, if one used some external tool to ensure that every file started with `Option Explicit` and `DefVar A-Z` and maybe some other standards (like `Option Base`), then you wouldn't need to worry about developers introducing the other Def*type* commands and having their co-workers wish their keyboard would electrocute them.

Comment: So `DefVar` would have been some kind of crutch then, a bit like `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` in VB.NET - the use case being to ensure backward-compatibility, at the cost of dealing with non-idiomatic code from another era. I hadn't realized `DefInt` was a thing (or maybe didn't remember.. I did transition from C64 to QBASIC) ...and since `Variant` came later, then `DefVar` was probably added because every other type had its `Def` statement: it was a catch-22 situation for Microsoft.

Comment: Also... I did preface the punishment with "willingly using them *in modern code*" - inheriting a legacy code base often yields all kinds of surprises ;-)

Comment: Yes, there is a *lot* of syntax and statements in Visual Basic which are basically there for backwards compatibility for people used to previous BASIC versions. I believe that's one of the main reasons why Microsoft thought it best to start afresh when they created V̶i̶s̶u̶a̶l̶ ̶F̶r̶e̶d̶ Visual Basic.NET, for better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

I remember FORTRAN where letters I to N were reserved for INtegers.
My first BASIC on the DEC PDP range had one-letter variables, with optionally one (or more?) numbers after the letter - so you could have I and I0 to I9.
I can't remember whether variables I to N were implicitly integer or whether the Def* keywords were introduced to enforce the rule.
There may be somebody who still has them in BASIC code migrated from 40+ years ago but I'd expect Rubberduck to flag them.
You do uncover some relics!

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to reflect reality* (-:

*Original post between ===== lines*

=================

A bit contrived perhaps, but there is a legitimate use case for `DefVar`: to override another `DefXxx`.
Suppose you had decided that you wanted almost all your variables and functions to be of type `Long`, so you included the statement:

`DefLng A`

But wait, you also wanted to reserve a couple of letters for the default type. This is accomplished with:

`DefVar P`

`DefVar V`

It's shorter and arguably clearer than setting out each range explicitly.

=================

After comments and a quick test it's plain that this isn't true any more, if it ever was. Still, I think what I posted next does show a reasonable case for at least one `DefXxx` statement:

As an aside, I preface every VB code module with

```
Option Explicit
DefObj A-Z
```

This forces me to explicitly type every variable and function, because almost nothing typed `As Obj` will survive as a common variable... it immediately throws an error to say (e.g.) `Abs(x)`, a clear indication that I've forgotten to assign X a specific type. Strong typing in an environment that discourages it.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but in [the VB6 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa263421%28v%3dvs.60%29) I see "Once the range A-Z has been specified, you can't further redefine any subranges of variables using Deftype statements. Once a range has been specified, if you include a previously defined letter in another Deftype statement, an error occurs." So I don't think you can "reserve a couple letters" like that. Though again, I haven't tried it, as it's been quite a while since I've used VB6, and perhaps this worked in prior BASICs.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. - I believe I've used it, but probably not in VB6 if that's what the docs say. I freely admit it was a contrivance and not something I'd actually use today.

Comment: Definitely not legal in VBA. This will throw up an error `Duplicate DefType Statement`. Furthermore, there is a subtle difference between a `Def[Type] A-Z` vs. say, `DefBool A-U, W-Z` & `DefVar V` -- the former will work even for variales like `âhhm`; it'll be implicitly boolean whereas latter won't even pick that up.